# Returning Multiple Row from Webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice, it doesnt error but give me only one row of data

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


namespace nikitaweb
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for nikitaws
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://ijportal.kemenkeu.go.id/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class nikitaws : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {


        public class Stndlist
        {
            public string nond { get; set; }
            public string nost { get; set; }
            public string tglst { get; set; }
            public string halst { get; set; }
        }

    [WebMethod]
    public Stndlist GetStnd()
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nikita_cs"].ConnectionString;
        List<Stndlist> Stndlists = new List<Stndlist>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            Stndlist daftarstnd = new Stndlist();
            SqlCommand da = new SqlCommand("xp_TampilStNd", con);
            da.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = da.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                daftarstnd.nond = rdr["nond"].ToString();
                daftarstnd.nost = rdr["nost"].ToString();
                daftarstnd.tglst = rdr["tglst"].ToString();
                daftarstnd.halst = rdr["halst"].ToString();
                Stndlists.Add(daftarstnd);
            }

            //JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            //Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(daftarstnd));
            return daftarstnd;

        }
    }

}
```

}

When i run the webservice only give me one row

```
<Stndlist>
<nond>ND-(002)/PP.42/2013</nond>
<nost>ST-(005)/PP/2013</nost>
<tglst>11/26/2013 12:00:00 AM</tglst>
<halst>Usulan Tugas Benchmarking ke Bandung</halst>
</Stndlist>
```

My objective is to return all row in my sql server database.
Can you tell me how can i modify this code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a collection of objects from your web service. The most convenient collection to use is `List<Stndlist>` in your case.  Use the code below for your web service method. The web service will automatically behind-the-scene convert the collection object to serialized JSON.

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Stndlist> GetStnd()
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nikita_cs"].ConnectionString;

        Stndlist daftarstnd = null;
        List<Stndlist> Stndlists = new List<Stndlist>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {

            SqlCommand da = new SqlCommand("xp_TampilStNd", con);
            da.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = da.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                daftarstnd = new Stndlist();
                daftarstnd.nond = rdr["nond"].ToString();
                daftarstnd.nost = rdr["nost"].ToString();
                daftarstnd.tglst = rdr["tglst"].ToString();
                daftarstnd.halst = rdr["halst"].ToString();
                Stndlists.Add(daftarstnd);
            }
       }
     return Stndlists;
  }
```

Comment: You have two variables with the same name.